# Sizes of the panels in Midnight Commander

Tags: midnight-commander

Can I change the height of the panels in Midnight Commander like in Far (pressing <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd>  or <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd> )?